# in kivy, changing the color does not work the way it's supposed to

Tags: python, kivy

i realized that for using RGB numbers in Kivy, we should divide them by 255,but that doesn't result the color it should.
for instance:

```
        self.btn5 = Button(text='click me!', background_color=(255/255,255/255,25/255))
        self.add_widget(self.btn5)
```

and the result:
it's like brown or sth similar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ63f.png)

what should i do? did i do something wrong during the installation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work as it is supposed to. Have a look at the [documentation for background_color](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.background_color):

> This acts as a multiplier to the texture colour. The default texture
> is grey, so just setting the background color will give a darker
> result. To set a plain color, set the background_normal to ''.

Comment: awesome, yeah , that's it. but what is the point of "background_normal" not being set ('') when we always have to set it ('') to get the colors right??

Comment: The default `background_normal` is an image that is grey, so your original post just multiplies that grey image by the `background_color` that you specified. Setting `background_normal` to `""` uses a plain white `background_normal`, so that white gets multiplied by the `background_color`, which results in just the `background_color`.